# I get a "Failed to load resource" for Cordova error when trying to run the blank ionic starter app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the blank Ionic starter app running (1.2.4); and I get this error after installing Ionic and trying to run their demo app:

Console:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on
>   this server. (cordova.js, line 0)

How do I resolve the 'failed to load resource' error for cordova?

Comment: You can't run plugins in your browser. They have to be run on the device (or sometimes in a simulator).

Comment: Oh so even if i use the phonegap app to view on my phone it would'nt work...I have to build ios app first and then give it a try?

Comment: Give it a try. I don't know what the phonegap view is so I can't speak to that.

Comment: Alright I will give it a try...thanks :)

Comment: and you did install `cordova`, right? because the `cordova.js` file is *not* in your www folder, which I'd expect it to be (your first error).

Comment: I'm using the ionic framework which is suppose to install the cordova.js file but I don't see it in folder tree...I tagged this post with ionic framework but I haven't heard anything from anyone else. I did follow the instructions perfectly and started a brand new project just to be sure

Comment: According to their website, your first step is to get node.js 4 installed, and then after that install cordova and ionic: 

http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Comment: I followed those instructions to the tee...I googled and it seems I need to emulate the app first and then the cordova.js file will be created...trying that right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Ionic Framework Website](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/), you need to do the following steps:

1. Install Node.js 4 (**Not Node 5**):

Using Homebrew:

- `brew tap homebrew/versions`
- `brew install node4-lts`

  2. when NPM is installed, run this:

     - `npm install -g cordova ionic`

That installs cordova and Ionic globally.

Once you do that, your `ionic start myApp starter` should build and install the necessary items to have a blank Ionic app.

I can't give you instructions on how to install it other ways (there are so many ways to install it depending on your OS.